# What is the lenght of the rope?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

The $E$ string of a violin has a linear density of $0.5 g / m$ and is subjected to a 
$80\text{N}$ of tension, tuned for a frequency $u = 660 \text{Hz}$:

1. What is the length of the rope?

I know that in order to answer the question I have manipulate the equation:

$$
\nu = \sqrt\frac{\tau}{\mu}
$$

Getting this equation:

$$
L = \frac{m v^2}{T}
$$

I have tried to find the mass but my attempts was unsucessufull.

I think that i could use the equation:

$$
f_1 = \frac{\sqrt\frac{T}{m/L}}{2L}
$$

In order to find the lenght, but I need help to find the mass of the rope.

Comment: You should define your variables. What are $\tau$, $\nu$, $v$, $\mu$, and $T$. I assume $L$ is the length of the rope.

Comment: Thanks for your commetary, but i already have found the speed  using the variables. In this case the speed is 12.65 m/s.

Comment: The mass of the rope (I prefer string) is the length times the linear density.

Comment: In this problem we don´t have the information about the mass of the rope. We have the tension, the frequency and the linear density.

Comment: m/L is the mass density, which you have (remember to put it in kg/m.
Then rearrange for the L in the denominator

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:
$$v=\sqrt{\frac {T}{m/L}}$$
and we have $m=\rho \times L$, or $\rho = m/L$. Which gives us:
$$v=\sqrt {\frac {T}{\rho }}$$
And frequency is:
$$F=\frac {v}{2L}$$
or 
$$2L=\frac {\sqrt {\frac {T}{\rho }}}{F}$$
Which finally gives us:
$$L=\frac {\sqrt {\frac {T}{\rho }}}{2\times F}$$
$$L=\frac {\sqrt {\frac {80N}{0.5g/m}}}{2\times 660 Hz}$$

Added: I also get 0.303 m

Comment: How is a newton defined in fundamental units?

Comment: 1 Newton is the force needed to move 1 kg with the accelaration of 1 m/s^2, or 1 Kg*m/s^2.

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra So, when you divide $80 kg·m/s^2$ by $0.5 g/m$, you get what?

Comment: I got it now. I will do de appropiate computations. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. How many wavelengths can you fit in a violin string? If $\ell$ is the length, then the wavelength is $\lambda = 2 \ell$.
2. Fundamental wave equation is that $\nu = f \lambda$, since you know frequency $f$ and speed $\nu$ you solve for $\lambda$ and hence $\ell$.

Comment: I have tried to use the wavelenght and the speed based on the frequency times wavelenght. In fact it must give the answer. In this case making the substituitions I found that the wavelenght is 0.019 and the lenght of the rope is 9.58x10^-3. The book´s answer is 0.3.

Comment: I don´t understand why I have - 2 in my reputation? What did i do wrong?

Comment: I did not -1 your question. Comments here are for answer specific discussions, and comments above are for question discussion.

Comment: I think your math may be mistaken somewhere. @LDC3 using the same method as me found 0.3m. Of course I did not want to give the answer away per our [tag:homework] policy.